# How to create a dictionary w/ key having multiple values from two lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list:

```
List2 = [Orange, Onions, Cherries, Steak, Chicken, Apples, Rice, Grapes]
List1 = [Fruits, Vegetable, Fruits, Meats, Meats, Fruits, Grains]
```

I want to be able to create the following dictionary where List1 is the Key:

OUTPUT:

```
Dict = {
         Fruits: Orange, Cherries, Apple. Grapes
         Vegetable: Onions
         Meats: Steak, Chicken
         Grains: Rice}
```

I tried something like:

```
List2 = [Orange, Onions, Cherries, Steak, Chicken, Apples, Rice, Grapes]
List1 = [Fruits, Vegetable, Fruits, Meats, Meats, Fruits, Grains] 

for e, f in zip (list1, list2):
     if e == set(e):
          for f in list2:
               d = {e:f}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object to accumulate values for the same keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst2 = ['Orange', 'Onions', 'Cherries', 'Steak', 'Chicken', 'Apples', 'Rice']
lst1 = ['Fruits', 'Vegetable', 'Fruits', 'Meats', 'Meats', 'Fruits', 'Grains']

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(lst1, lst2):
    d[k].append(v)

print(dict(d))
```

---

```
{'Fruits': ['Orange', 'Cherries', 'Apples'], 
 'Vegetable': ['Onions'], 
 'Meats': ['Steak', 'Chicken'],
 'Grains': ['Rice']}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Solution works fine w/out the need of additional modules @communitybot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score -1):

i think the solution:

```
key = set(list1)
dict={}
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
     for k in key:
       if x == k:
         dict.setdefault(k,[])
         dict[k].append(y)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).